# Do Docker containers share a single Python GIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, containers, virtualization

When I run a Python script inside a Docker container, it completes one execution loop in ~1 minute.  Now as I spin up 2 more containers from same image, and run Python scripts inside them, everything slow down to a crawl and start requiring 5-6 minutes per loop.

None of the scripts are resource bound; there is plenty of RAM and CPU cores sitting around idle.  This happens when running 3 containers on a 64-core Xeon Phi system.

So does Docker share a common Python GIL lock among all containers? What are my options to separate the GILs, so each process will run at its full potential speed?

Thank you!

Comment: If I am not terribly mistaken about how docker works they should not share a GIL. That does not mean that there is not contention for some other resource between the different instances of the scripts. However, to provide more answers we would need to see the script.

Comment: Docker doesn't impose anything on Python scripts. Docker containers are just a collection of processes with a smaller view of the overall system and specific resource limits for that collection. Can you confirm this problem doesn't happen if you simply run multiple versions of your scripts in parallel without invoking Docker?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Running multiple Python scripts on localhost shares a GIL lock and thus runs single-threaded.  I am trying to overcome GIL and utilize multiple cores by running multiple Docker containers with Python scripts inside them.

Comment: @Kingua: Running multiple Python programs does _not_ share a GIL. Each Python program is a separate process. A process has its own Python interpreter. The GIL only operates on _threads_ - a process may have multiple threads, so if you run a single process, create multiple threads, and then execute CPU tasks, only then does the GIL apply because all threads share the processes's interpreter. Multiple processes do not have the GIL. Your slowdown is not because of the GIL, and Docker will not help or hurt.

Comment: @all Thank you for your pointers!
I have been investigating since yesterday, and I see a lot of soft page faults in memory so it seems like a cache miss issue.

Comment: I am planning to do the same to improve the performance of my python flask app.
For the research I found out we have to create a new network for these containers & all traffic should map to this network. Hence each request should be passed to a different container in a round robin manner.
Could you please share how you manage this?

Answer (score 2):

> So does Docker share a common Python GIL lock among all containers?

NO.

The GIL is per Python process, a Docker container may have 1 or many Python processes, each with it's own GIL.

If you are not multi-threading, you should not even be aware of the GIL. Are you using threads at all?

Comment: I have multi-threaded FOR loops using job-lib, however I have also tried single-threaded FOR loops with same result.

Comment: @Kingua is there anything in contention between these processes? Are they doing any kind of IO? Database queries? If you have quiet cores, there is something else causing them to block each other out. What happens when you run them OUTSIDE of docker containers?

Comment: Script is not I/O bound, as it loads a single image and does a whole bunch of image manipulations on it for 10 seconds.  
I have been investigating this since yesterday, and I see a lot of soft page faults in memory so it seems like a cache miss issue.